# How can I npm link the module in React project?

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, npm-start, npm-link

I working on a `React` project and I want to modify one of the `module`. Below is my step.

```
File tree:
  /project
    package.json
    /project_need_module (the sub module)

1. cd /project/project_need_module
2. npm link
3. cd /project
4. npm link project_need_module
```

But there is a compile error saying module not found. do I have to add a line like

```
"project_need_module": "file:/project/project_need_module"
```

in `package.json` with `npm install`? Cheers